# how to have many objects or models in one form with spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i have to use one form for two modelAttributes : "groupes" which is a list of Groupe and "matieres" is a list of Matiere, i know that one form support only one modelAttribute , i tried two options but both doesn't work,one by using spring bind tag and the other one by wrapping groupes and matieres in one class,
Any ideas how to solve this ?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("abs");

    mv.addObject("matiere", matiereservice.findAlmatieres());
    mv.addObject("groupe", groupeservice.findAllGroupes());

    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm( @ModelAttribute("groupe") Groupe groupe, @ModelAttribute("matiere") Matiere matiere,
        ModelMap map,
        BindingResult result
         ) {
           // BindingResult treatment

    return "listeleve" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending those attributes separately, simply make a DTO class which contains `List` fields of both of your `Groupe` and `Matiere` classes.

```
public class ListeleveDTO {
    private List<Groupe> groupe;
    private List<Matiere> matiere;

    public ListeleveDTO(List<Groupe> groupe, List<Matiere> matiere) {
        // Assign to fields
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

And set the instance of this class as a model attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("abs");

    mv.addObject("listeleveDTO", new ListeleveDTO(groupeservice.findAllGroupes(), matiereservice.findAlmatieres());

    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm( @ModelAttribute("listeleveDTO") ListeleveDTO,
        ModelMap map,
        BindingResult result
         ) {
           // BindingResult treatment

    return "listeleve" ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ,i tried that and an error occured when submitting the form  : HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect, do you have any idea about this problem?